# Passing a Variable in PHP to the simplemodal

Tags: php, variables, simplemodal

So hi guys. I have a problem regarding a variable passing. I can't explain it clearly but here's the code. I know it'll be clearer with this.

```
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['nameSchool'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['honor'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['year'] ?></td>
    <td width = "5%"><div id='basic-modal-2'><a href="?idnum = <?php echo $row['countr']; ?>" title = "Edit" class = "basic"><img src="../img/edit.png" height="22" width="22"></a></div></td>
    <td><a href="#" title = "Delete"><img src="../img/Delete.png" height="22" width="22"></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
        }
?>
    </tbody>

   //some codes here.

<!-- Update Employee -->
<div id="basic-modal-content-2">
    <h3>Update Information</h3>
    <p></p>
    </br>
    <form method="post" action="add3.php">
        <table id = "box-table-c2" class = "basic-modal-content-2">
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong><?php echo $_GET['idnum']; ?></strong></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name = "NS"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name = "ad"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Honors Received</strong></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name = "HR"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Year Graduated</strong></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name = "YG"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align= "left" width= "3"><button class="btn-primary" type="submit" style = "cursor: pointer";>Submit</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

They are both on the the same php file (educinfo.php)

My error is that i can't pass the value of the "EDIT" link to the simplemodal.

Thank You guys.

Comment: `$Idvalue = isset($_GET['idnum']) && !empty($_GET['idnum']) ? $_GET['idnum'] : "";`. use `echo $Idvalue` instead of `echo $_GET['idnum'];`. idnum value can avail only after clicking edit link.

Comment: i'll try this one. Thank you. things are getting clear to me now.

Comment: i tried this, and still no luck, the $_GET['idnum'] : ""; is the one being read. i clicked the link, and still empty

Comment: Did u noticed address URL. URL have idnum value. Post URL after clicked link

Comment: once i hover my mouse on it (on the EDIT link). it got its value. but wen i clicked, it gives me a blank result.

Comment: Well I really can't get it done, but i found another approach. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass value in PHP using many ways. one way is passing value in Query String. That is you can pass value after file name with question mark. just like key value passing

```
phpfilename.php?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

You can pass any number of key and value. After that you can access in next page using key value.

In HTML Part:

```
<a href="filename.php?QueryString=valueOne" title = "Edit" class = "basic">
     <img src="../img/edit.png" height="22" width="22">
</a>
```

In php you can get like this

```
$Idvalue = isset($_GET['QueryString']) ? $_GET['QueryString'] : "";
```

Please let me know if you have any issue for passing value like this

Comment: Exactly? i am kinda new to php... it says undefined index. ? can you explain further what does this code do? I tried that one you gave me, but it displayed nothing.

Comment: <a href="#?idnum = <?php echo $row['countr']; ?>" title = "Edit" class = "basic"><img src="../img/edit.png" height="22" width="22"></a> I used this, now i want to pass the idnum to my modal, but it displays an empty result.

Comment: Please remove ` # ` in your edit link that's problem.

Comment: By the way. i should pass the variable on the same page. This flow : CLICK link(the one I showed above) > simplemodal appear > displaying the value I stored on the link. Hope you get my point. And Big Thanks

Comment: ofcourse, your answer helps me. but still, i can't get the idnum thrown on the modal, it displays undefined. I dont know maybe because they are on the same page?

Comment: Where is your **modal** code and where you get **idnum** code

Comment: There, i updated my code on the question. They are both inside my educinfo.php. Thank you for helping me figure this out. So my echo $idnum on the modal is to check if i am really getting the value on the link